# MySQL update date where date is 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

I imported some data from excel onto my database. Due to some formatting errors, many of the ship dates are "0000-00-00". I want to change that to NULL. I used the following query but it doesn't work. Can someone show me the correct syntax?

`UPDATE inventory SET shipdate = NULL WHERE shipdate IS '0000-00-00'`

Comment: It should work. Perhaps your date field is flagged as `NOT NULL` and it can never be null.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE shipdate IS '0000-00-00'
```

should be

```
WHERE shipdate = '0000-00-00'
```

`IS` operator is used **ONLY** to compare with `NULL` or `NOT NULL` values, like `col IS NULL`.

In all other cases the equality is checked with `=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and `WHERE shipdate = '0000-00-00'` was also not working for me.
So i found a solution.
Your query should be looks like this:

```
UPDATE inventory SET shipdate = NULL WHERE shipdate = 0
```

Please try it and let me know.
Thanks.